# Multiple calls to the GitHub API

Tags: c#, performance

I have the following class:

```
public class IssueWithComments : Issue
{
    public IReadOnlyList<IssueComment> FullComments { get; set; }

    public IssueWithComments()
        : this(new List<IssueComment>())
    {
    }

    public IssueWithComments(IEnumerable<IssueComment> comments)
    {
        FullComments = comments.ToList();

    }

    public static IssueWithComments FromIssue(Issue issue, IEnumerable<IssueComment> comments)
    {
        return new IssueWithComments(comments) 
        {
            Assignee = issue.Assignee,
            Body = issue.Body,
            ClosedAt = issue.ClosedAt,
            Comments = issue.Comments,
            CreatedAt = issue.CreatedAt,
            HtmlUrl = issue.HtmlUrl,
            Labels = issue.Labels,
            Milestone = issue.Milestone,
            Number = issue.Number,
            PullRequest = issue.PullRequest,
            State = issue.State,
            Title = issue.Title,
            UpdatedAt = issue.UpdatedAt,
            Url = issue.Url,
            User = issue.User
        };
    }
}
```

where `Issue` is a type defined in the [`Octokit.Net`](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net) namespace.

I populate my objects by calling the following code:

```
public static async Task<IReadOnlyList<IssueWithComments>> GetAllForRepositoryWithComments(this IIssuesClient client, string owner, string name)
{
     var issues = await client.GetAllForRepository(owner, name);
     List<IssueWithComments> all = new List<IssueWithComments>();

     foreach (var i in issues)
     {
         all.Add(IssueWithComments.FromIssue(i, await client.Comment.GetAllForIssue(owner, name, i.Number)));
     }

     return all;
 }
```

This works, but just takes 7.640 seconds on average according to `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` (plus that I can see it taking a long time to load).

`Task.WhenAll` could work, but the way to find the `Issue` it is referring to is as follows:

```
x.FullComments.First().HtmlUrl.Segments[4]
```

Is there a better way to either run the loop or should I go with `Task.WhenAll` and drill into the URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're loading all comments for all issues, I think

```
await client.Comment.GetAllForRepository(owner, name)
```

is what you're looking for. Otherwise, if you do need to use `GetAllForIssue`, try using `Task.WhenAll` to run comments retrieval in parallel:

```
public static async Task<IReadOnlyList<IssueWithComments>> GetAllForRepositoryWithComments(IIssuesClient client, string owner, string name)
{
    var issues = await client.GetAllForRepository(owner, name);

    return await Task.WhenAll(issues.Select(async i => IssueWithComments.FromIssue(i, await client.Comment.GetAllForIssue(owner, name, i.Number)));
}
```

Comment: The first option would not work, as there is still no way to comfortably map the results to the appropriate issue. Your code - while very marginally slower then a fix I was working on - is much cleaner so you get the accept.

Comment: By the way this cuts it down from the `7.640` seconds mentioned in the question to an average if `1.5` seconds